# Wifi not working on fresh ubuntu installation on new computer

Tags: wireless, internet

I got the new HP all-in-one desktop with no OS. Installed latest Ubuntu. During installation it asked about wifi connection details which i provided. After restart, booting first time, i fond the wifi connection established but internet not working. Please suggest / help.

Comment: is secure boot turned off? Check it in the BIOS menu

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Internet connection maybe something different from wifi connection . If you can connect to your wireless access point it means you don't have any trouble with you NIC .

For troubleshoot this problem you may provide more detail about your Routing table and DNS configuration .

For getting know about these detail , try :

```
 $ ip a
```

which show your run time networking status . Check If your connection has IP and CIDR ( /x ) is as same as your network ( Some issue for some routers ) .

```
 $ ip route show
```

This will show you routing tables . Check **default** parameter is set correctly and also is same as **UG** flag in following command `route -n` .

After these you can try to checking your DNS configuration . Check `/etc/resolv.conf` if Network manager wrote right nameserver . Also check `/etc/hosts` to check if there is any mistyping . Also check `/etc/nsswitch` for getting know about which DNS configuration read first .

In any steps if you want to do any changes do not edit it by hands . Network manager has great utility for managing them **nmcli** .

Try to make new profile :

```
 $ nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname wlp18s0 con-name ali save yes
```

Then modify your connection :

```
$ nmcli connection modify ali ipv4.address 1.2.3.4/24
```

And you can find out more options to edit profile when you enter *ipv4.* press TAB .